# Select a select value to send in emailscript

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get a mail script to work (well, it's working except for one part). I added a dropdown menu, but for some reason it's value is empty when reading the mail that was sent.

The dropdown menu that I got:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Type werkzaamheden</label>
            <select type="select" id="select" name="select">
            <option value="kameronderhoud">kameronderhoud</option>
            <option value="glas-bewassing">glas-bewassing</option>
            <option value="specialistisch reinigen">specialistisch reinigen</option>
            <option value="vloer-onderhoud">vloer-onderhoud</option>
            <option value="woningontruiming">woningontruiming</option>
            <option value="gevel-onderhoud">gevel-onderhoud</option>
            <option value="overige">overige</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

These are my POSTS:

```
$tel        = $_POST['phone'];
$name       = $_POST['name'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$email2     = $_POST['email2'];
$select     = $_POST['select'];
$comments   = $_POST['comments'];
$phone      = $_POST['phone'];
```

All of them work except select.

Edit: here is the full form

```
$e_body = "Er is contact opgenomen door $name." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "<br><br>

                Gegevens:<br>
                Naam:       $name <br>
                E-mail:     $email <br>
                Tel:        $phone <br>
                Type:       $select <br>
                $commentsb<br> " . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "    $email2";
```

Everything displays correctly except the select part. Anybody know what could be causing that?

If it's needed, here is a working part of the form (HTML):

```
<form method="post" id="contactform" name="contactform" class="contact-form" action="mail/contact.php" type="contact">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h2 class="short">Vraag een <strong>Offerte</strong> aan</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Uw naam*</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name"  class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Uw mail*</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email"  class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label>Type werkzaamheden</label>
                <select type="select" id="select" name="select">
                    <option value="kameronderhoud">kameronderhoud</option>
                    <option value="glas-bewassing">glas-bewassing</option>
                    <option value="specialistisch reinigen">specialistisch reinigen</option>
                    <option value="vloer-onderhoud">vloer-onderhoud</option>
                    <option value="woningontruiming">woningontruiming</option>
                    <option value="gevel-onderhoud">gevel-onderhoud</option>
                    <option value="overige">overige</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label>Uw telefoonnummer</label>
                <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label>Onderwerp</label>
                <input type="text" id="email2" name="email2"  class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label>Bericht</label>
                <textarea cols="6" rows="7" id="comments" name="comments" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder=""></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right" value="Verstuur">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

PHP script:

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;


// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

    $tel        = $_POST['phone'];
    $name       = $_POST['name'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $email2     = $_POST['email2'];
    $select     = $_POST['select'];
    $comments   = $_POST['comments'];
    $phone      = $_POST['phone'];



if ($_POST['form_type'] == 'contact'){

}else{

if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div style="color:red;border:solid 1px red;" class="alert alert-error">Vul uw naam in.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div style="color:red;border:solid 1px red;" class="alert alert-error">Vul uw email adres in.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div style="color:red;border:solid 1px red;" class="alert alert-error">Vul een geldige emailadres in.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($phone) == '') {
    echo '<div style="color:red;border:solid 1px red;" class="alert alert-error">Vul uw telefoonnummer in.</div>';
    exit();
} 

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}

}

// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

//$address = "example@themeforest.net";
$address = "*email*";



// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';
if ($_POST['form_type'] == 'contact'){
$e_subject = 'Terugbelafspraak';
}else{
$e_subject = 'Contact Form';
}

// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

if ($_POST['form_type'] == 'contact'){

$e_body = "Er is een terugbelverzoek  gemaakt." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "Nummer: $tel";

}else{

if($comments == ''){
    $commentsb = '';
}else{
$commentsb = 'Bericht:'.$comments.'';
}


$e_body = "Er is contact opgenomen door $name." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "<br><br>

                Gegevens:<br>
                Naam:       $name <br>
                E-mail:     $email <br>
                Tel:        $phone <br>
                Type:       $select <br>
                $commentsb<br> " . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "    $email2";
}
$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: *email*" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

if ($_POST['form_type'] == 'contact'){

    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>";
    echo "<h3 style='text-transform:none;'>Aanvraag is verzonden.</h3><br>";
    echo "<p>Er zal zo spoedig mogelijk contact opgenomen worden door ons.</p>";
    echo "</div>";

}

if ($_POST['form_type'] != 'contact'){

    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>";
    echo "<h3 style='text-transform:none;'>Email is verzonden.</h3><br>";
    echo "<p>Bedankt <strong>$name</strong>, uw mail is ontvangen door sfsdf.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
}

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

Comment: **Side note:** You should really sanitize and validate ***all*** user input.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I am not validating everything yet, only $name $email and $phone.

Comment: Whats the output of var_dump($select) ?

Comment: check `POST` Params in header after submitting form.

Comment: try `var_dump($_POST)`  and see if u are getting `select`.

Comment: @Shaeldon the output is NULL

Comment: With $_POST the output is: array(5) { ["name"]=> string(4) "etew" ["email"]=> string(17) "email@email.com" ["phone"]=> string(6) "235235" ["comments"]=> string(6) "gsdgsd" ["email2"]=> string(5) "dsgsd" }

Comment: @user50248 can you paste the HTML code that is within the FORM element. ?

Comment: see there is no $_POST['select'].. post the full form code instead.

Comment: seems your 'select` element is after form is closed. Put your html code for form

Comment: I posted the full form in the original question.

Comment: it seems correct for select.. is there any js or other script?

Comment: No all the validation is done in php, this is the whole form. No js or anything.

Comment: I copied your code and run into my server.. and it's working.. I got all `$_POST` values, including `$_POST['select']`

Comment: I do have another contact page that uses the same email script, but that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @ShaunakShukla weird, so it's something in my php file, I'll post the whole script, one sec.

Comment: @user50248 in you code you use `$select = $_POST['werkzaamheden'];` but based on your HTML it should be `$select     = $_POST['select'];`

Comment: @ojovirtual Oops, I added my edited php script, I edited it back, select is correct, 'werkzaamheden' is not in my file at the moment.

Comment: How can we get `$_POST['form_type']`? this couldn't be found in form!

Comment: BTW, I'm still getting correct mail with correct posted values.. `Gegevens:
Naam: erwer
E-mail: shaun@gmail.com
Tel: asdad
Type: woningontruiming
Bericht:dasdasd
dasd`

Comment: You used my whole PHP script? Or used your own?